# How to find the highest and lowest oxidation state of transitional metal

Tags: electronic-configuration

My teacher taught me the formulas 'nS' and 'nS+(n-1)d' to find the highest and lowest oxidation state of transition elements. He gave the example of $\ce{Mn}$ and showed that the numbers were +2 and +7. But I did not understand it. So can please you give me
a good explanation.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! Please have a look at the [help] and take the [tour]. Could you explain, what the variables in your formula stand for, please.

Comment: @Martin Although OP should confirm, the "n" stands for the principal quantum number as "s" and "d" refer to the s and d orbitals.

Comment: Electron configuration [Ar] 3d5 4s2 - could you be more specific about your lack of understanding? ;)

Comment: Well … what about $\ce{Mn2(CO)10}$ and $\ce{[Mn(CO)5]-}$?